# Android SharedPreference Values load automatically

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In the code written below whenever my cart activity is launched and when the compiler reach on line : `HashMap<String, String> cart = session2.getUserDetails();` then it by default loads the default item values instead of loading null values The values loaded are the values given in previous run. Can anyone pleas suggest me where i am wrong in my code?

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lvCartItems;
Button bClear;
Button bShop;
TextView tvTotalPrice;

// Session Manager Class
ProductSessionManager session2;

ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<CartItem>();
Context context = Cart.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    textHome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_home);
    textSchedules = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_account);
    textMusic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_cart);
    tvTotalPrice=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTotalPrice);

    lvCartItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCartItems);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();


    // Session class instance
    session2 = new ProductSessionManager(this);


    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> cart = session2.getUserDetails();

    // item
    String item1 = cart.get(ProductSessionManager.KEY_item1);
    //quantity
    String quantity1 = cart.get(ProductSessionManager.KEY_quantity1);
    //rate
    String rate1 = cart.get(ProductSessionManager.KEY_rate1);
```

Comment: Kindly clear your shared preference values when it is no longer needed!

Comment: `Use HashMap<String, String> cart = null;` Instead `HashMap<String, String> cart = session2.getUserDetails();` !

Comment: that's the whole point of using Sharedpreferences to maintain the session. It'll retain previous values till either you update them or clear them. If you don't want the previous values clear your shared preference.

Comment: @tahsinRupam -  your suggestion will produce null pointer on this line of code : `String item1 = cart.get(ProductSessionManager.KEY_item1);`

Comment: @MarkKeen Yeah, definitely. If he wants null value he should remove them to or clear the Preference key value. This will also give him null value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to clear your session.

```
 SharedPreferences pref  = 
 context.getSharedPreferences("shared_preferences_name", "mode");   
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
 editor.clear();
 editor.commit();
```